# Tail-recursive flatten function in Emacs Lisp

Tags: elisp, on-lisp

I'm going through Paul Graham's [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html), and trying to implement the functions in Emacs Lisp.
One of them is flatten :

```lisp
(flatten '(a (b c) ((d e) f)))
;; Returns:
(a b c d e f)
```

Yet for some reason, the implementation given by Paul Graham does not work on Emacs Lisp (always returns nil):

```lisp
(defun flatten (x)
  (cl-labels ((rec (x acc))
              (cond ((null x) acc)
                    ((atom x) (cons x acc))
                    (t (rec (car x) (rec (cdr x) acc)))))
             (rec x nil)))

(flatten '(1 (3)))
;; Returns:
nil
```

Does it have something to do with ELisp's dynamic binding? What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Drop the last closing paren from  `((rec (x acc))` since that just defines `rec` to be function returning `nil`, changing it to `((rec (x acc)`, and then put the closing paren at the end of the whole `cond` expression so that `cond` becomes the body of `rec`.

Comment: Ouch. Thank you, you nailed it. Copy-paste is not possible from the book, and even though I checked ten times the syntax, I missed the paren. Tried to debug, but debugging on labels is not easy for a beginner.

Syntax is :

(cl-labels ((FUNC ARGLIST BODY...) ...) FORM...)

Question answered.

Comment: By the way, Emacs doesn't implement tail-call optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment to the question, the problem is a misplaced parenthesis. The definition should be:

```
(defun flatten (x)
  (cl-labels ((rec (x acc)
                   (cond ((null x) acc)
                         ((atom x) (cons x acc))
                         (t (rec (car x) (rec (cdr x) acc))))))
    (rec x nil)))
```

In the original, `((rec (x acc))` defines `rec` as a function returning `nil`. By changing it to `((rec (x acc)` the `cond` expression becomes the body of `rec`, and then after balancing the parentheses again by adding a closing parenthesis after the `t` clause of the `cond`, the `flatten` function works as expected:

```
(flatten '(1 (3)))
(1 3)
```